# Get the strings after dot in R

Tags: r

```
x = c("Apple.4XD", "Home.23", "Tea.459", "So.5S6")
y = c("Apple22.1/Apple23", "Home.23/Home.2S/Home")


sub("\\..[0-9]?", "", x) 
sub(".*/", "", y)

x : got output is 

[1] "AppleXD" "Home"    "Tea9"    "SoS6"

y : got output is 

[1] "Apple23" "Home"
```

But I want get  x is `"Apple.4" "Home.2", "Tea.4", "So.5"`,
y is `"Apple23" "Home2"`

I only want get 1 digit after dot.

How can I get the result in R? Thanks!

Comment: In y `"Apple23"` is not just one digit after the dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex captures everything up to the first dot, the dot itself and one digit after the dot.

```r
x = c("Apple.4XD", "Home.23", "Tea.459", "So.5S6")
y = c("Apple22.1/Apple23", "Home.23/Home.2S/Home")

sub("^([^\\.]+\\.[[:digit:]]).*$", "\\1", x)
#> [1] "Apple.4" "Home.2"  "Tea.4"   "So.5"
sub("^([^\\.]+\\.[[:digit:]]).*$", "\\1", y)
#> [1] "Apple22.1" "Home.2"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Maybe the following solves the problem in comment.

```r
x = c("Apple.4XD", "Home.23", "Tea.459", "So.5S6")
y = c("Apple22.1/Apple23", "Home.23/Home.2S/Home")

getPattern <- function(x) {
  pattern <- "^([^\\.]+\\.[[:digit:]]).*$"
  s <- strsplit(x, "/")
  sapply(s, \(y) sub(pattern, "\\1", y))
}

getPattern(x)
#> [1] "Apple.4" "Home.2"  "Tea.4"   "So.5"
getPattern(y)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "Apple22.1" "Apple23"  
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "Home.2" "Home.2" "Home"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi, if y want to get the no.3 value after slash ,  like "NA" and "Home", how could I chang your code?

Comment: For the sake of brevity (and transparency) you could shorten `sub("^([^\\.]+\\.[[:digit:]]).*$", "\\1", x)` to `sub("([^.]+\\.\\d).*", "\\1", x)`  - no need to anchor match, no need to escape `.` in character class, why (on earth) use `[[:digit:]]`  (11 chars!) rather than `\\d` (3 chars)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more transparent solutions:

in `base R`:

```
sub("(.*\\.\\d).*", "\\1", x)
```

where `(.*\\.\\d)` is a capture group capturing the substring you are after, i.e., from the start of the string including any characters up until the dot `.`and the `\\d`igit; this substring is recollected by the backreference `\\1`.

with `library(stringr)`:

```
str_extract(x, ".*\\.\\d")
```

where the desired substring is matched and yanked out.

Data:

```
x = c("Apple.4XD", "Home.23", "Tea.459", "So.5S6")
```

(tbh, it's unclear to me what, or based on what logic, you want to extract from vector `y`)

Answer (score 0):

The second one is not clear. But for the first one. I have used tidyverse to get the output.

```
x = c("Apple.4XD", "Home.23", "Tea.459", "So.5S6")
y = c("Apple22.1/Apple23", "Home.23/Home.2S/Home")
library(tidyverse)
str_extract(x, "([A-Za-z]*\\.[0-9]).*?")
```

Here is the output:

```
> str_extract(x, "([A-Za-z]*\\.[0-9]).*?")
[1] "Apple.4" "Home.2"  "Tea.4"   "So.5"
```

And for the second one.

```
pattern = "/([A-Za-z]*?\\.?[0-9]+).*?"
str_match(y, pattern)[,2]
```

Here is the output:

```
> str_match(y, pattern)[,2]
[1] "Apple23" "Home.2" 
>
```